# How to place an anchor point exactly between two others in Photoshop CC?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, creative-cloud, anchor-point

In such a situation,
how can you center the middle point?

[image: illustration]

Comment: If you have found any of the answers below to have answered your question please make sure to mark it as the accepted answer.  If the answers do not answer your question please make an [edit] seeking clarity.

Answer (score 2):

You may also solve that problem by simple geometry trick :)
Create a circle with a center at the end point of line segment and a radius a little bit greater than a half of the line segment. Then put a copy of the circle at the other end of it. The circles will intersect at two points. When you connect that points with a straight line it will intersect your line segment exactly in the half way. I attach a picture to make it more clear.

I know it's quite time-consuming and inefficient, but dealing with life by doing math is cool B)[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unless that changed in the CC version you need to do it manually - figure out the width in px and move the anchor point either by dragging it or using the keyboard. Photoshop is not the greatest at dealing with vectors.

Answer (score 1):

You might also try using the Rectangle Tool (since you can snap a guide to the exact center) or use a Grid (view>show>grid) with Snap to Grid (view>snap to>grid). Place a rectangle and snap a guide to the center then remove any extra anchors. Obviously not ideal, but a bit faster than trying to count pixels.

Answer (score 0):

Adding my method in case it helps. This is in Illustrator CC 2019--I can't say much about older versions. I had an object where I wanted to add a single anchor point on one small straight path, equidistant from either of the two surrounding anchor points.

1. Use the **Scissor Tool** (C) and **cut the two anchor points between which you want to add a new anchor point**; this gives you a completely separate line segment.
2. **Select the now-disconnected line segment** (easiest for me to use the Layers panel and select it there since it's not really visible at this point--I didn't have any stroke in my example).
3. Click **Object** > **Path** > **Add Anchor Points**; this adds the one anchor point exactly between the other two.
4. Use the **Direct Selection Tool** (A) and **drag over JUST ONE of the corners** where the anchor points were cut in step 1.
5. Use **Ctrl+J (Cmd+J on Mac)** to join the anchor points.
6. **Repeat steps 4 and 5** for the other anchor points cut in step 1.

   *Edit: By the way you can use the Selection Tool (V) instead, select the whole object, and use Object > Path > Add Anchor Points, but this adds one anchor point between **all** existing anchor points, which is not what I was after. I tried using the Direct Selection Tool and just selecting the one segment I wanted to manipulate but it still added anchor points on all the segments in the object instead of just the one.

Comment: The question is about Photoshop CC